# Sauce with Jalapeno, garlic, cumin and lime?

Tags: sauce, jalapeno

I created this sauce/topping with chopped jalapenos, fresno chilies,minced garlic, cumin, olive oil and lime or lemon juice. I used it as a topping for steak or fish. I'm pretty sure I've had this type of sauce or something close to it at restaurants and wondered what the name of that type of sauce would be?

[image: Here it is on a steak I made]

Answer (score 2):

This looks great, and if it was offered in a restaurant I expect it to be called a 'Fresh Jalapeño Salsa'.  That would give me all the information I would need when deciding to order or not.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, it was delicious. I also do a lot of salsas but I have put cumin in one before but your right, all the other elements are pretty much in a salsa. The one key ingredient that is missing is tomato, that to me would make it a salsa 

Comment: Yes, a very good comment about the tomato, however, I think you have rocked it with this one.

Comment: Tomato is not necessary for a condiment to be identified as a salsa. See: salsa verde, for example.

Comment: I guess I assumed salsas need to contain tomato, but yes I've seen a salsa verde which usually has tomatillos.

Answer (score 1):

> wondered what the name of that type of sauce would be?

As you commented in another Q, *salsa* would be out, as that leads to tomato.

- Your dominant ingredients are peppers (chilies, jalapeno): *pimiento* or *aji*
- Your preparation is chopped: *picada*.
- Looks spicy: *picante*

Combinations that come to mind:

- Picante Picada Pimiento
- Picada Pimiento
- Picante Picada Aji
- Picada Aji

Because Pimiento is often lacks spice (think of the ones stuffed into olives), I like **Picada Aji**.

Of course, Spanish has many dialects and Picada Aji may not make any sense in some areas. Locale dialect needs to be considered.

I only understand enough Spanish to eat.

Comment: I think your word order is wrong. Spanish puts adjectives after the words they modify. So your "preferred" one should be "aji picada". That being said, as a Texan I've never heard the word "aji" so I don't know if it's a good option.

Comment: Regionalization affect. Aji  http://www.limaeasy.com/peruvian-food-guide/typical-aji-chilli-peppers . Visually, the OP dish reminded me of http://www.baldmanrecipes.com/colombian-aji-sauce-aji-de-paula/